# looping through grid elements

Tags: android, grid-layout

I am trying to make a simple tic tac toe game. I have already written the logic for deciding who has won and a text field displays the winner. As soon as someone has won I am making a reset button visible. And I have set the onclick attribute of the button to a function reset who does this

```
public void reset(View view){
        for(int i=0;i<playerAt.length;i++)
            playerAt[i]=2;
        activeGame=1;
        activePlayer=1;

        Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        but.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        GridLayout grid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid);

        for(int i=0;i<grid.getChildCount();i++){
            ImageView block = (ImageView) grid.getChildAt(i);
            block.setImageDrawable(null);
        }

    }
```

I have researched for the way to loop through grid objects on this site only but it doesn't seem to work. As soon as I press the button the app closes in the emulator. If I remove the loop and instead run a simple loop like

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
```

Then it works without fail but obviously, it will not do anything. Basically, I want my reset button to clear all the entries in a grid layout. I have their images of black and red dots which I want to clear.

But this way I am not able to do it.

I also tried this without using a loop

```
ImageView block = (ImageView) grid.getChildAt(0);
block.setImageDrawable(null);
```

But again same result: app closes down as soon as the button is pressed.
Probably this is the not the way in the latest android studio version
If you want to look at my complete code in the MainActivity.java file then here it is

```
package com.example.nik7.tictactoe;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.nio.InvalidMarkException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int activePlayer = 1;
    int activeGame = 1;
    int [][]winningP = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
    int []playerAt = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void drop(View view){
        ImageView block = (ImageView) view;
        int currentPosition = Integer.parseInt(block.getTag().toString());

        if(activeGame==0)
            return;

        if(playerAt[currentPosition]==1 || playerAt[currentPosition]==0)
            return;

        playerAt[currentPosition] = activePlayer;

        if(activePlayer==1) {
            block.setImageResource(R.drawable.black);
            activePlayer = 0;
        }

        else{
            block.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
            activePlayer=1;
        }


        //check if someone has won
        for(int[] wp:winningP){
            if(playerAt[wp[0]] == playerAt[wp[1]] && playerAt[wp[1]] == playerAt[wp[2]] && playerAt[wp[0]] != 2){
                activeGame=0;
                Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
                TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

                but.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                text.setText((activePlayer==1)?"red has won":"black has won");
            }
        }
    }

    public void reset(View view){
        for(int i=0;i<playerAt.length;i++)
            playerAt[i]=2;
        activeGame=1;
        activePlayer=1;

        Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        but.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        GridLayout grid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid);

        ImageView block = (ImageView) grid.getChildAt(0);
        block.setImageDrawable(null);


    }











}
```

Comment: try this....        void resetGame(){
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
    }

Comment: take all imageviews in an array or list and on reset set all to drawable you need to set. rest all code remains same.

Comment: @W. Seun you are right. It got working. But what's the problem with approach I mentioned

Comment: @user2779311 I didn't get what you are trying to say. Can you please elaborate what chunk of code you want me to add

Comment: @NikhilRathore I think it's unable to get reference to a view or maybe a cast problem, you should check the error log generated when it crashed, this should give you an overview of what's going wrong. Just that your reset method is not nice enough as you're recreating too many objects in the loop when you can actually just reInstantiate the whole gridLayout it self once without a Loop...

Comment: @NikhilRathore and also if you don't mind simple upvote the comment as helpfull.

Comment: ImageView iv[]=new ImageView[noyouhave]. In the onCreate initialize all. In your reset use a for loop to re set background to null. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem with the log is that some content is added every second and it is constantly moving. I mean it is not stable

Answer (score 1):

try importing

```
import androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout;
```

instead of

```
import android.widget.GridLayout;
```